# Cancel request for web resource in WebView2

Tags: webview2

I am developing an email application where I would like to display mail messages in WebView2. I would like to give a choice to the users to download or not remote resources in Html mail messages(for security reasons). How can I cancel requested resource in WebView2?

I tried subscribing for the event
webView.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;

but when the event handler is invoked I don't see a way to cancel the request.

Comment: Do not ask the same questions here and on GitHub.

Comment: Why I can't do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to cancel a request to a resource is to set the `Response` property of the `CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs` parameter to a **dummy response**.

However, before you do that, you have to call `CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter`to specify which resource types you want to trigger the `WebResourceRequested`event.

Here is an example, that will filter out all requests to images:

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;

private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
}

private void WebView21_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webView21.CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested += CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested;
    webView21.CoreWebView2.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter(null, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2WebResourceContext.Image);
    webView21.CoreWebView2.Navigate("https://stackoverflow.com");
}

private void CoreWebView2_WebResourceRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2WebResourceRequestedEventArgs e)
{
        e.Response = webView21.CoreWebView2.Environment.CreateWebResourceResponse(null, 404, "Not found", null);
}
```

You can of course and more filtering logic, if you like.